# is there a relation between optimization and compression?

Tags: performance, optimization, compilation, compression, compiler-optimization

Optimization is doing more computation with less.
Compression is saying more with less.
Is there a relation between the two? Can you compress computations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Good question.
The connection is [*Information Theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).
Let me simplify it enormously:

There is a difference between an amount of a) data, and b) information.
Data is a physical quantity of something, such as bits on a disk or on a communication line.
Information is what it tells to whomever is reading it, and as a measure it is always less than or equal to the data that carries it.
The amount by which the data exceeds the information that it carries is called its *redundancy*.
What compression does is reduce the data so it is closer to its information content, by reducing the redundancy.

What about computation? Think of a program as an information channel taking input data and processing it to recognize its information.
When the program has finished, it "knows" a certain amount of information about the input.
Every elemental operation it performs is one in which it gains (or loses) information, and it is not finished until it gains all the information.

Example: Searching for a particular key value in a table of 1024 numbers.
When the key is found, 10 bits of information have been learned, because it takes 10 bits to indicate where the number is in the table.
If binary search is used, it requires 10 comparisons, so each comparison is "learning" one bit.
There is a faster method if the key can be used as an index directly into the table.
In that case, the operation of indexing "learns" all 10 bits in a single step.
There is a slower method - linear search, which takes, on average, 512 comparisons.
In that method, each comparison only gets a fraction of a bit.
(That's why it's slow.)

So if computer operations are like data, optimization tries to minimize the number of operations for a given amount of information, while compression tries to minimize the number of data bits for a given amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common trade-off in algorithms: trade extra space for faster computation (lookup table with possible values), or the opposite (binary search or similar). I'd recommend a read on space and time complexity. You may be able to find some neat tricks helping you optimize or compress, whichever you need more.